# Can an iOS PhoneGap app return to the app after a call has been done?

Tags: cordova

I have a hybrid PhoneGap application which allow the user to call a phone number. This switched to the Phone app. When the user ends the call he is stuck in the Phone app and the desired behavior would be to automatically return to the actual application.
Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the tel: intent you have to use the telprompt intent. This prompts the user with the number he is about to call with the option to either call or cancel.
Example:

```
window.location = 'telprompt://' + phoneNumber
```

When the user hangs up he is returned to the app.